# I have `Total Number of Seats` and `Available Seats`. How do I manage the two?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I struggled to come up with appropriate title for this thread.

Forgive me it isn't clearcut.

We have a table called Locations with following attributes:

locationID --Each location has 30 capacity seating per class
Capacity_Seating --this is total allowed seat per class per location.

When a user logs in, s/h is presented with a dropdownlist of locations to choose from. Whichever location the trainee chooses, is the location s/he is going to take the training at.

The Capacity seating for each location is 30.

As soon as the user logs in, s/he is taken to the Trainring page. The training displays general information about the classes, including the date and time of training, duration, the Capacity Seating and most importantly, available seats or Seats remaining.

If seats are still available, the user can click Register to register for that particular training.

Once this user is registered, the available seat changes.

For instance, if there were 15 seats prior to this trainee registering, then after registering, the available seating with now read 14 seats.

If a user chooses to cancel his or her seat after initially registering, the trainee can do so as long as it isn't within 24 hours of training date.

Here are my questions.

1, do I need to add another field called `Available_Seats` to the location table or to the Training table to show how many seats remain or can this be done using a query like:

Select (`Capacity_Seating` - each time trainee registers)?? Not sure how to handle this.

2, We would like to use register to substract a number from `Capacity_Seating` and `Cancel` to put back a number to `Capacity_Seating`.

Your thoughts and assistance are greatly appreciated.

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:LinkButton ID="Btncalc" runat="server" Text="Register" tooltip="Click to calculate" onclick="calc" />
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
</ItemTemplate>
```

---

Sub calc(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim objConnection As SqlConnection

```
Dim username = Session.Item("Username").ToString
' Dim strSQL As String
objConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBConnectionString").ConnectionString)
objConnection.Open()

strSQL = "update TrainingTable set employeeId='" & username
strSQL += "', AvailableSeats= AvailableSeats-1"
strSQL += " where location = '" & ddlLocation.SelectedValue.ToString & "'"
'Response.Write(strSQL)
'Response.End()
Dim cmdcommand As New SqlCommand(strSQL, objConnection)
cmdcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

cmdcommand = Nothing
objConnection.Close()

objConnection = Nothing
```

End Sub

By the way, markup is on gridview.

Comment: How about starting with question #1?

If coding makes you happy, help yourself. I ask for any ideas, suggestions, thoughts on how to approach the problems I listed and they are much appreciated.

Comment: That will be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question how you would like to proceed mostly comes down to what you would like to do. Having another field for the available seats in a table or finding the remaining seats using a query are both viable options. The benefits or pitfalls of either are really negligible given the basic structure of your system. Seeing as you would use a specific query to find this piece of information constantly it would be better practice and sense to add this value in as a new field in the table. This will eliminate the need for a specific query and make this data more public to other systems and queries.

For your second question I'm not quite sure I follow it but I'll try to give you my best opinion. It seems you want to alter the total capacity field from each table based on registrations and cancellations which I would disagree with. The capacity value shouldn't be modified if the actually total capacity of location does not change. So rather than changing the total capacity through cancels or registrations I would change that new available seats field. This leaves no chance for confusion when viewing the capacity of the location and will easily allow you to find the available spaces for registration.

Comment: sorry about the confusion. What I meant to say was that assume that Capacity_Seating is 30 as it were in reality, then if a trainee registers, then that is akin to substracting 1 from Capacity_Seating and then displaying remaining seats.

In other words, we still would like to say, Capacity_Seating for this class is 30 but availabling seating is 29.

Same logic when a registered trainee cancels, then that seat will be added back so that we have Capacity_Seating = 30; available seating = 30.

I just need help with pseudocode for coding it and I can code from there.

Comment: Ok so you simply want to update the available seating. I would take your available_seating field in your table and update it UPDATE table SET available_seating = available_seating +- 1. Change the +- to whatever you need depending on the situation. I think this is along the lines of what you want but the way you go about this may change based on what database and system you are using.

Comment: i am using sql server database.

I guess my biggest issue is how to handle when the mode is registration or when the mode is Cancel so I can say if mode='Register' then updqate table set available_seat=available_seating-1, etc

Comment: Sounds about right. If you wanted to since you are keeping track of the number of registrations as well you could also calculate it by update table set available_seating = seating_capacity - count(registered_trainees) or something like that. The count() would likely have to change depending on the type of results you want in your query.

Comment: Ok, that make sense. How should cancellations be calculated?

Comment: The last query outline I gave you would work for both registration and cancellation. All you need to do is insert or delete a user from the database before you do the calculation. Otherwise if you had say mode="Cancel" then update table set available_seating = available_seating + 1.

Comment: But how do we know the original value for available_seating?

Do we start it off with same number as Capacity_Seating?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple module:

It gives you a choice of a particular course, with two venues and an option of reg or adv course at each venue (this doesn't affect the seating)

I have NOT included the SQL OR server side scripts, at this stage.. this algorithm should help.
You don't need to add another column to your table, just update the fields as the program is implemented, and you can delete a row, if it is cancelled. I haven't included code for that.. (it's too long!!! hahaha)

(NB this doesn't error check for datatype - it's a simple format to get an idea)

```
Module Module1


Sub main()
    Dim Seat As Object
    Dim Course As Object
    Dim Person1 As Integer
    Dim Venue1 As Integer
    Dim Venue2 As Integer
    Dim regular As Integer
    Dim Advanced As Integer
    Dim x As String

    Do
        Person1 = Person1 + 1
        If Venue1 = 30 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Venue1 is full")
        End If
        If Venue2 = 30 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Venue2 is full")
        End If

        Console.WriteLine("enter 1 for Venue1, 2 for Venue2")
        Seat = Console.ReadLine
        If Seat = 1 Then
            Venue1 = Venue1 + 1
        Else
            Venue2 = Venue2 + 1
        End If
        Console.WriteLine("Regular course = 1, Advanced course = 2")
        Course = Console.ReadLine
        If Course = 1 Then
            regular = regular + 1
        Else
            Advanced = Advanced + 1
        End If

        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue, r for reports or x to quit")
        x = Console.ReadLine
        If x = "r" Then
            Console.WriteLine("total Persons= " & Person1 & vbCrLf & "total Venue1= " & Venue1 & vbCrLf & "total Venue2=" & Venue2 & vbCrLf & "Course: regular " & regular & vbCrLf & "Advanced " & Advanced)
        ElseIf x = "x" Then
            Exit Do
        Else
        End If
    Loop Until Person1 = 60
    If Person1 = 60 Then
        Console.WriteLine("Course is full.")
    End If

End Sub
End Module
```

Please let me know if you need any more help or clarity.

Comment: Thank you very much @yvytty.

This is the second time someone had asked the query, `what have you already done` and the individual actually help.

Problem is this way too complicated for what I am trying to accomplish. I wouldn't know how to integrate this with my gridview code.

Comment: Thank you.

I decided to go with my gut feeling by adding a new field called RemainingSeats with default size of 30 like the Capacity_Seating.

Then using Andrew's logic, each time there is a new registration, 1 seat is removed fom RemainingSeats. This works now.

There is still a problem though. You will have to log off and log back in to see the new value for remainingSeats. 

Although the user will be redirected to main page after registering, we would like to see changes as soon as user clicks Register.

I have updated main question with latest code.

Thanks a lot